# Number of SQL Injection keywords in csv file line Python

Tags: python, csv, counter, sql-injection

Im trying to count the number of SQL Injection keywords in a csv file line ie, 'SELECT | UPDATE | INSERT | CREATE| ALTER | RENAME | WHERE | DROP' so i can find out how many keywords are in each request.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: keywords = ['SELECT | UPDATE | INSERT | CREATE| ALTER | RENAME | WHERE | DROP']
 with open('SQL injection.csv') as f:
 for line in f:
  sum(line(str(keywords))

Comment: there is no such thing like "SQL injection keywords"

Answer (score 0):

Try pat = re.compile("Select|update").  Then len(pat.findall(line)).

I.e you are usining a regex to find a match to any keywork, then you get the lenght of the list all found matches.